# Efficiently updating Multiple api-based UI Router Views in Angular 1.2 using directives

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular 1.2 application that I suspect is in a less than optimal state. I am in the process of implementing ui-router and trying to clean up the logic overall.

Currently I have two views that make separate calls to an API service.

One view lists all the record in the database, and the other allows the user to add/edit a record. They are simultaneously in view. The add/edit view is a partial overlay.

The add/edit view contains all the logic in the controller and exists as an HTML template with no directives.

The listing view uses a simple directive that transcludes a more complex directive, and all the logic exists in the directive controller of the more complex directive.

When the user adds/edits a record, I want to update the listing without refreshing the page. What is the best practice for binding the data to both of these views?